# Avoid a .toString call in REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I have this class with a `.toString` method, that generates a huge JSON object, and caches it in a lazy val ... Trying to investigate some weirdness going on with that json generation, I want to create an instance of the object in REPL, but not have `.toString` called just yet.

What I came up with is this:

```
 class Foo(val x: MyActualClass)
 val foo = new Foo(new MyActualClass)
```

I wonder if there is a better way. Like is there some command to just tell REPL I don't want to print out the results of the assignments for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:silent` to do this:

> :silent                  disable/enable automatic printing of results

Comment: Great, thank! Don't know how I missed it in :help output :/